# Nginx alias configuration for API with Silex

Tags: api, nginx, php, silex

I've a problem with my NGinx configuration, I know there is a lot of topics already, but I didn't manage to my working properly...

So I've mydomain.com and mydomain.com/api/, my folders are like:
/var/www/mydomain.com/website/dist and /var/www/mydomain.com/api/public

And at the moment, I've something almost working. But the index.php still get the /api part in my routes.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        root /var/www/mydomain.com/website/dist;
    }

    location ~ ^/api(/|$) {
        root /var/www/mydomain.com/api/public;
        try_files $uri /api/index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index           index.php;
            fastcgi_pass            unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
            include                 fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param           APPLICATION_ENV production;
        }

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Authorization';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
    }

    access_log /var/logs/nginx/logs/mydomain.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/logs/nginx/logs/mydomain.com-error.log;
}
```

I guess I'm not understanding something with the location or with php-fpm. What did I miss ? What should I do to get this working properly ?

I read too that a try_file is enought for that, than a rewrite rule... I don't know :/

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do? Are you getting an error or is some URL in your config not redirecting or proxying correctly?

Comment: No, it's "working" but not as I would like.
I get `No route found for "GET /api/": Method Not Allowed (Allow: OPTIONS)` and should be `No route found for "GET /": Method Not Allowed (Allow: OPTIONS)`

And also, I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it.

Comment: Are you saying your request URLs should be ``/index.php`` instead of ``/api/index.php``? You can try using ``rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 last;`` where you have ``try_files $uri /api/index.php;``

Comment: Yes the /api/ should be transparent indeed. It doesn't work, same as before, with the try_files

Comment: You have 2 ``try_files`` commands in your /api location block. One uses ``/api/index.php`` and the other ``/index.php``. What is the exactly path to the ``index.php`` file relative to your root path (``/var/www/mydomain.com/api/public``)?

Comment: `/var/www/mydomain.com/api/public/index.php` yes

Comment: My bad, the rewrite print me the main page, the one in `/var/www/mydomain.com/website/dist`

Comment: Sorry, I was sidetracked by something else. I think if you keep what you originally have and it's working, that's probably the most compatible configuration you can have. As I understand what you're trying to do, you want "/api/index.php" to appear as "/index.php" to your PHP framework -- is that correct? I don't think there's a way you can do this with your nginx settings -- since any URLs your PHP framework emits has to have the /api/prefix or else none of the URLs will work (because they will end up going to your "/' site. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you want your API URLs to use "/index.php" etc. without the "/api" prefix, I think your the best alternative is to use a different subdomain (like "api.mydomain.com" instead of sharing the api with your main domain (www.mydomain.com or domain.com).

Comment: I'm not agree with the fact my routes should contain /api/ and if tomorrow I want to put my api in a subdomain ? And I can't I'm on a SaaS application and I don't want api.team.mydomain.com :) I'm pretty sure there is a way, there is always a way :p

In fact, what I want is a alias for the subdomain, /api/ (pointing on `/var/www/mydomain.com/api/public`) to transparently redirect every requests like it was `/api/index.php/users/8`

Comment: Your API app probably emits URLs as end-points for web services. So if it refers to /index.php (because it's configured to use / and not /api as a prefix, this will go to your regular site (and not back to your API). Your API needs to use a different set of URLs than your regular website or use a different subdomain. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yeah... you're right. It make sense.
So I will modify what I need, and put my api in `api.mydomain.com`. it will be 1 api for all my tenants but they are identified by a tenant_id so it could work. Thanks for the advice !